# Is it possible to get feedback on duplicates with SqlBulkCopy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I'm using SqlBulkCopy to insert into a table with IGNORE_DUP_KEY on. This means that exceptions aren't thrown when duplicate is encountered, instead it passes over it and continues.

Is it possible to get feedback on which rows were inserted or ignored?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.

Not without using a staging table and seeing what is missing after moving to the real table, or checking for dupes after loading the staging table